# Unity3d strange Collider behaviour

Tags: unity-game-engine

I found something I can't understand. I'm only a beginner, so I thought I could use the CarController Scripts of the Car Demo for making a little driving game with different models. 
[image]

the Car demo I wonder why the colliders are sub-objects and the RigidBody has "Gravity-Enabled" without falling apart.

[image]

my try to copy my model falls apart with the same configuration.

1.what's exactly my mistake?

2.How can I fix this?

3.Should I rather write a script for applying the gravity to my model?

Comment: What do you mean by 'falling apart'? Looking at your screenshot you did not use the same configuration (e.g. mass of rigidbody).

Comment: after some seconds only the tires are standing on the ground, the rest falls through the ground

Comment: Do you have isTrigger enabled? Disabling that could fix it.

Comment: IsTrigger is disabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely all of your objects with Colliders have also Rigidbody component. Try removing all these components and leave only one on a root object.

Comment: You can have child objects with a `RigidBody` component (this is useful in some cases for detecting collisions on specific parts) but they should have their `IsKinematic` property set to `true`.